# Remove GitHub pull request of someone else

Tags: git, github, pull-request

One of my repositories on GitHub got a pull request by someone who left their email and password to login in the code. Since the repository is public, everyone could potentially see that pull request. Is there a way for me, as owner, to delete the PR from existence?

Comment: https://newbedev.com/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github

Comment: Yes, but you should consider those credentials already totally compromised.

Comment: @matt I'll definitely contact them to make sure they know they have to change their credentials. Thanks cmgchess for the url!